# Bulk upsert in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I want to insert `10000` data into the `couchbase`, but only part of data has been inserted successfully. I have tried several times and the number of data that has been inserted successfully is different everytime.

How can I insert all the data into `couchbase`?

```
bucket, _ := myCluster.OpenBucket("test", "")
for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
    s := strconv.Itoa(i)
    batch = append(batch, &gocb.ReplaceOp{Key: s, Value: "test"})
}

err = bucket.Do(batch)
```

There are two pictures about the bucket.

Bucket before operation:

[image: bucket before operation]

Bucket after operation:

[image: bucket after operation]

Answer (score 3):

You could try dynamically writing a long N1QL query, of this form, but longer:

```
INSERT INTO test(KEY, VALUE) VALUES ("1", {"a": 1}), ("2", {"a": 2}), ("3", {"a": 3})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have a try in this way. And I have found the answer about the question that part of my data insert failed.[https://issues.couchbase.com/projects/GOCBC/issues/GOCBC-231](https://issues.couchbase.com/projects/GOCBC/issues/GOCBC-231)